# Rank mismatch in Keras

Tags: python, keras

I have a method that calculates the loss between the  output layer of a network and the input target labels that I give as input during training. My code looks like:

```
def get_loss(y_pred, y_true):

   y_true = tf.cast(y_true, 'int32')
   loss = tf.nn.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(labels=y_true, logits=y_pred)
   # loss shape : <tf.Tensor 'softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits/Reshape_2:0' shape=(?,) dtype=float32>
   mask = tf.cast(tf.not_equal(y_true, 0), 'float32')
   loss = tf.reduce_sum(loss * mask, -1) / tf.reduce_sum(mask, -1)
   loss = K.mean(loss)
   return loss

src_seq_input = Input(shape=(None,), dtype='int32')
# <tf.Tensor 'input_1:0' shape=(?, ?) dtype=int32>
tgt_seq_input = Input(shape=(6,), dtype='int32')
# <tf.Tensor 'input_2:0' shape=(?, 6) dtype=int32>
enc_output = self.model(src_emb, src_seq, active_layers=active_layers)
# <tf.Tensor 'layer_normalization_5/add_1:0' shape=(?, 6) dtype=float32>
loss = get_loss(enc_output, tgt_seq_input)
```

When I try to run the last line of my code I am receiving the following error:

> ValueError: Rank mismatch: Rank of labels (received 2) should equal rank of logits minus 1 (received 2).

What exactly that error means, and why possible may be wrong in the combination of my tensors?

**Edit:**
I modified the cross_entropy from sparse to be dense: `softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits_v2` or `softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits` now the error that I am receiving is the following one:

> *** tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: Incompatible shapes: [32,6] vs. [32]
>            [[{{node Equal_1}} = Equal[T=DT_INT32, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"](_arg_input_4_0_1, Cast_9)]]

Comment: Why do you have a shape to `None`?

Answer (score 1):

The error means that labels (`y_true`) must have one dimension less than logits (`y_pred`).

It also says that your `y_pred` is 2D, and that your `y_true` is 2D.

Well, if your `y_pred` is 2D, then your `y_true` should be 1D.

It looks like your model outputs 6 classes and your `y_pred` is shaped `(batch_size, 6)`. Thus, your `y_true` must be shaped `(batch_size,)`.

---

Now, if your `y_true` is one-hot, you should not be using "sparse" but just a normal crossentropy.

Pay attention to the shape of the `loss` (after crossentropy), it's probably 1D as the classes dimension probably collased.

Comment: They should not be same sized? Since I would like to calculate the error?

Comment: You're using "sparse" crossentropy, which means you are passing the labels as "a number" not as one-hot encoding. But `y_pred` is always 1-hot.

Comment: Maybe then it is the cast function that I need to skip, right?

Comment: Then what should I define as a target input in here:

tgt_seq_input = Input(shape=(6,), dtype='int32')?

Comment: I finally modified, the cross-entropy to be the normal one: tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits or v2. Now I am receiving another error: *** tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: Incompatible shapes: [32,6] vs. [32]
         [[{{node Equal_1}} = Equal[T=DT_INT32, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"](_arg_input_4_0_1, Cast_9)]]

Comment: Probably because `mask` is 2D and `loss` is 1D in `loss*mask`.

Comment: This error comes when I am trying to run my model, not during the compile and the calculation of the loss. Until now my error was during the compile of the model (that was containing the posted code).

Comment: Yes, shape mismatch errors can happen in runtime if shapes are unknown at compile time

Comment: But which shape is the issue (is it tgt_seq_input?),  how can I define properly?

Comment: Check all your shapes step by step, check that your results are what you expect.

Comment: Is there a way at least to compile and track the shape that I missing? To get more info from the error.

Comment: Usually I do `print(K.int_shape(tensor))` for every tensor I'm in doubt.

Comment: What is your mask and what do you expect it to do?

Comment: Mask does not change the size of the y_true, it returns the same size. Even if I comment it out the error is the same. I can debug the code but only during compiling, not during fitting.

Comment: Already from the line with the crossentropy (loss = tf.nn.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(labels=y_true, logits=y_pred)) the results is <tf.Tensor 'softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits/Reshape_2:0' shape=(?,) dtype=float32>.

Comment: Yes, shape `(32,)`, now what is shaped as `(32,6)`? The mask.

Comment: Hmm yes, the mask has the size of y_true. So they kind of having different sizes.  However, now that I change sparse to dense cross-entropy it seems to me that I got the complaint that my input is sparse but the loss computes dense.

Comment: I do not understand the input to get_loss is the same (?, 6) and (?, 6) while the output is (?, ?).